# how to set timer in a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a jumble game in python that works well but once I tried to add a feature to my program, I couldn't find the solution...
**I want to add a timer to my program that stops everything & finish the game after e.g. 1 min.**
here's my code:

```
from random import choice, shuffle
import os

words = ['hello','honey','green','horse','rose','window','virus','traffic','yard','camel',
'ground','tutle','earth','internet']
count = len(words)
os.system('clear')
true_answer, false_answer = 0, 0

while(count!= 0):
    word = list(choice(words))
    new_word = "".join(word)
    shuffle(word)
    user = input(f'Can you guess what this word is ({" ".join(word)}) ? ')
    if new_word == user:
        true_answer += 1
    else:
        false_answer += 1

    count -= 1
    words.remove(new_word)
    os.system('clear')

print(f'true answers : {true_answer}\nwrong answers : {false_answer}')
```

**I want that the player would only play for 1min & after that sees his result.**

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime library, get the time on start and make a loop that checks if time is over, here is an example https://tecadmin.net/get-current-date-time-python/

Also you can do

```py
import time

startTime = time.time()
# when you when you want to start measuring time
.....
# do it in a loop
if(time.time() - startTime > 60): # 60s
   print("Time has elapsed")
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's a problem: time is paused when the program wants the player type in an input... I want it to work no matter the user gives the input or not.